# How to create an array with number of elements from a variable?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an integer `num` that was read from a file. I want to create an array with the number of elements being `num`.

A sample code of what I want to do but doesn't work:

```
int num;
cin >> num;
int iarray[num];
```

Comment: `std::vector<int> ar(num);`, assuming of course you checked the return value of that read op *and* ensured `num` is a reasonable value (i.e. not negative, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in C++ have compile-time bounds.

Use dynamic allocation instead, or a healthy `std::vector` wrapper around the same process.

Answer (score 1):

dynamic allocation being `int * iarray = new int[num];`

Just make sure to call `delete[] iarray;` at some point to free the memory.